# ssh: connect to host ::1 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, ipv6

I can't figure out why I can't connect to my Raspberry Pi using ssh over IPv6.

I've modprobed the ipv6 module and modified /etc/sysctl.cfg to include

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

I also explicitly added

```
Listen ::
```

to my /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

I can ssh *out* to other machines using ipv6; and I can ssh *in* using ipv4. But connecting using

`ssh ::1`

gives me

`ssh: connect to host ::1 port 22: Connection refused`

(This also happens when I try to connect from an external box, but I figure I have to fix being able to connect to localhost before I try outside addresses.)

It doesn't seem to be a firewall issue. ip6tables tells me

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

So it doesn't look like there's any there there.

What else could be blocking me from connecting via ipv6?

(And yes, in theory I could just give up and go back to my NATted IPv4 address, except that this is a Kodi machine, and I'm setting up a share over a VPN for my media files, and the VPN is set up for ipv6.)

This is on Xbian 10, which is based on Raspbian via Debian buster.

Thanks.

Comment: So netstat is showing the ssh port open on IPv6? Does the sshd log contains any entries if you try to connect?

Comment: Good questions. netstat doesn't show a listener on port 22 for tcp6, so looks like for some reason the daemon isn't listening for ipv6 connections even though I specified "Listen ::".

Comment: Please [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/127606/edit) your question and add the output of this command to it: `ip addr`.